# One user with several profiles (pages)

Tags: 7, users

What modules are available (profile2 would come in handy i guess) to create something like pages on facebook.
Like on facebook each containing description, galleries and some other content i make available.
All handled by user who created pages.

I have idea in theory how would each user create pages, but i have no idea how would he for example when uploading gallery tell Drupal that the gallery he just uploaded belongs to page 3, while this user has 10 pages.

Answer (score 1):

The 'edit own' permission should be all you need. Allow the user to create content of a specific node type. Put a gallery, description and any other fields on it.

A little more detail:

1. Create a content type 'Pages'.
2. Make sure users can create new pages and edit own pages.
3. The user makes as much 'Pages' as he wishes.
4. Put a gallery and any other fields on the content type.

If you want to use other content types instead of fields, use entity reference.

Comment: I think you have not read the question. Each user can create several profiles (like facebook pages) where he uploads images or puts news. Its easy to create gallery but its not easy to make gallery belong to only one of the pages user picks.

Comment: I did read the question. :-) I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: Ok, ill clarify the question. Imagine identical website like myspace. But the main differnce is that one user with same login/email can create several bands. Now the problem is, after 1 user created 10 bands is that he wants to upload image gallery that belongs to band nb.5. Yes he can create as many bands and as many galleries but he cant tell Drupal that gallery he is creating right now will belong to band5, and show only on band5 profile.

Comment: Are you using a module to create the gallery? Or how did you configure it?

Comment: Media module. But that is not important.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill, but have you looked at the Organic Groups module?

Allow each user to create their own Group. Create different content types associated with groups.